# Where to ask a question about outlook.com?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask a question about the outlook.com platform and their SPAM control system ?

The issue at hand:

> One of our domains is constantly marked by [Outlook](https://outlook.com/) as SPAM, while
>   all the setup is adequate and properly validated by many on-line
>   tools, among those, the [mxtoolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/).
>
> How can we query Outlook technical support about this issue ?
>   *or*
>   How can we obtain technical detail about their classification of our messages so we can understand the issue and deal with it ?

Comment: After reading suggested websites help pages, I've found serverfault to be the best fit for this issue, as this subject directly concerns the mail server and its layers of configuration. The question can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/q/896143/128973).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally was thinking about [webapps.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), but most of those seem to be user-level questions.

I would probably try there first, but they might redirect you to our general server/admin site, [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: A certain amount of server administrator, experienced is assumed at Serverfault.  It is doubtful the author's question, as it's written' would be well received at Serverfault.

Comment: After reading the Web Applications Help page, regarding [on-topic subjects](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), seems clear that a technical issue isn't appropriate to that website, as it seems to be best suited for applications usage from the end-users perspective. Thank you for your suggestion, but I've gone with [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/896143/128973) for this one.

Answer (score 3):

[Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com) seems to me like it would be the right place. There are a lot of questions there tagged with [email](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) that seem to be asking about messages that get caught in spam traps.

This is definitely *not* a question for [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com).

Comment: After reading the Webmasters Help page, regarding [on-topic subjects](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), seems clear that a technical issue isn't appropriate to that website, as it seems to handle only upper layers on the development stack. Thank you for your suggestion, but I've gone with [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/896143/128973) for this one.